# replacing last part of string after pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

What is the best way to remove the last bit of a string, following a certain recognized pattern?
For example:

`s = 'some Strings-and-stuff - SomeOther Strings-and-stuff - TAke.THis last -part away.txt'`

will return:

`'some Strings-and-stuff - SomeOther Strings-and-stuff'`

when operated on by some function which looks for the pattern '`-`' and removes the last string after the last `' - '` occurs.

**EDIT: The answer was given to be:**

```
new_string = ' - '.join(s.split(' - ')[0:-1])
```

*Other things I tried:*

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.*) - ', '', s[::-1])[::-1]
'some Strings-and-stuff'
```

Using the suggested `.split()` function, I can get the output by this:

```
>>> p = s.split(' - ')
>>> p.pop()
'TAke.THis last -part away.txt'
>>> ' - '.join(p)
'some Strings-and-stuff - SomeOther Strings-and-stuff'
```

It works, but the other suggested answer is a better way to get rid of the non one liner `pop()` or `del` function.

Comment: Split by " - ", remove the last piece and implode the rest.

Comment: How is the initial part of the string recognised?

Comment: He actually wants two of those parts after the hyphen to be removed. @chase I guess you'd have to provide what kind of pattern you want to remove in order for me to suggest a regular expression for that.

Comment: Sorry the pattern to recognize is '` - `' with a space on either side of the `-`.  Everything past the last '` - `' is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you the desired result in a single line:

```
s = " - ".join(s.split(' - ')[:-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to use split for this!

```
In [130]: s = 'some Strings-and-stuff - SomeOther Strings-and-stuff - TAke.THis last -part away.txt'

In [131]: s.split(" - ")[0:-1]
Out[131]: ['some Strings-and-stuff', 'SomeOther Strings-and-stuff']
```

when you split by " - " it will return a list that has items that would have been separated in the string by " - ".

Then you index from the first item until the last item, which is why there is `[0:-1]` after the split